# Counterexample for two equal series?

Tags: analysis

The folowing result is well known.
Given two absolutely convergent  infinite sequences of complex numbers $\{a_n\},\{b_n\} $ such that
$$\sum_na_n^k=\sum_n b_n^k$$
for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, after some rearrangement, $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$.

Now can you give me some counterexamples to show that the absolute convergence cannot be dropped?

Comment: You can take any series that does not converge absolutely and make them converge towards anything you want with some rearrangement.

Comment: What do you mean by the two sequences being absolutely convergent? Do you mean that the series $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ are absolutely convergent?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Yes

Comment: @Lelouch But we need the infinite power sums of them are equal.

Comment: Study the proof to figure out where absolute convergence is used. Then figure out why it was used. Is there anyway to bypass the requirement?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Maybe I need to point ojt the existence of some counterexamples. And the proof is is totally formal.

Comment: "The proof is totally formal" - What do you think that means, and why do you think it is even relevant to what I said? Absolute convergence had to come up in the proof, or it wouldn't have been assumed. Go find out why. And if you know that there are counter-examples, why are you asking if some exist? That is exactly the question you asked. I gave you an approach to figuring out counter-examples yourself. I make no claim it is easy - real math is hard - but it is how mathematicians discover things.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Soory,  I have modified my problem.

Comment: To find a counter example see where absolute convergence is used in the proof and see if you can find a sequence that fail the step that that step requires.

Comment: Absolute convergence is used to a rearrangement to get the index of greatest absolute value. If there is only one $k$, the problem is easy. However,  we need to handle on countable $k$.